# IE9 stopped working with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new to selenium, I am using following code snippet to automate menu items[ajax].

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor;
executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver; 

executor.ExecuteScript("return $(\"a:contains('" + category + "')\").mouseover();");
executor.ExecuteScript("return $(\"a:contains('" + subCategory + "')\").click();");
```

On mouse-over submenu will be opened. I am getting a popup message, IE stopped working at times. How to get rid of this behaviour.

Comment: What are 'category' and 'subCategory'? Can you provide us some more info?

Comment: Category is main menu element, subcategory is submenu element. On mouseover on main menu item, it will expand submenu and we need to select submenu item.

Comment: "IE stopped working"? How? Does it error? Does it crash? Any different with IE8? Can you reproduce it on another machine? What version of Selenium and the IEDriver? Did this just start happening?

Comment: I am using Selenium and IEDriver 2.33.0.0. This is happening IE 9, not sure about IE 8. Yes I am able to reproduce in other machine. I think I need to give wait between javascript functions.